# Cannot wait until the entire DOM is loaded with Scripty Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I've used the [Scripty extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/scripty-javascript-inject/milkbiaeapddfnpenedfgbfdacpbcbam) to inject some JS code in a page which aims to notify me whether a certain string is present in a table.

The code detection code seems to work fine. I've tried to launch a snippet via Chrome which works, but through this extension it doesn't seem to work.

I strongly believe it's a matter of the DOM not being completely loaded, since outputting the size of my `querySelectorAll()` result gives me 0.

I've tried different approaches like `document.onload` or `document.onreadystatechange` or selecting the option to run my code on page load (through Scripty extension). This is my code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
    console.log("permission is not granted!")
    Notification.requestPermission()
  }

  let available = document.querySelectorAll("td")
  let availableCondition = true;
  
  for (let index = 0; index < available.length; index++) {
    console.log(available[index].innerText)
    if (available[index].innerText.toLowerCase().includes('la sede non offre')) {
      availableCondition = false
      break
    }
  }

  if (availableCondition) {
    new Notification("Appuntamento disponibile")
  } else 
    location.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your code once the DOM is ready, use the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event